# Can't set headers after they are sent error on PUT request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I get the **Can't set headers after they are sent** error everytime I try a PUT request on the specified route. And I couldn't figure out whats the problem here. I am also getting a 200 response, but the data is not updated in the database.

Here is my code:

```
episodeRouter.route('/:episodeId/comments/:commentId')
.get(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, function (req, res, next) {
    Episode.findById(req.params.episodeId)
        .populate('comments.postedBy')
        .exec(function (err, episode) {
            if (err) next(err);
            res.json(episode.comments.id(req.params.commentId));
        });
})

.put(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, function (req, res, next) {
    // We delete the existing commment and insert the updated
    // comment as a new comment
    Episode.findById(req.params.episodeId, function (err, episode) {
        if (err) next(err);
        episode.comments.id(req.params.commentId).remove();

        req.body.postedBy = req.decoded._id;

        episode.comments.push(req.body);
        episode.save(function (err, episode) {
            if (err) next(err);
            res.json(episode);
        });
    });
})

.delete(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, function(req, res, next){
    Episode.findById(req.params.episodeId, function (err, episode) {
        if (err) next(err);
        episode.comments.id(req.params.commentId).remove();
        episode.save(function(err, resp) {
            if (err) next(err);
            res.json(resp);
        });
    });
});
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)
at ServerResponse.header (H:\COURSERA\FULL STACK WEB DEVELOPMENT COURSE\CAPSTONE PROJECT\Capstone Project\watchours\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:719:10)
at ServerResponse.send (H:\COURSERA\FULL STACK WEB DEVELOPMENT COURSE\CAPSTONE PROJECT\Capstone Project\watchours\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:164:12)
at done (H:\COURSERA\FULL STACK WEB DEVELOPMENT COURSE\CAPSTONE PROJECT\Capstone Project\watchours\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:956:10)
at Object.exports.renderFile (H:\COURSERA\FULL STACK WEB DEVELOPMENT COURSE\CAPSTONE PROJECT\Capstone Project\watchours\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:374:12)
at View.exports.__express [as engine] (H:\COURSERA\FULL STACK WEB DEVELOPMENT COURSE\CAPSTONE PROJECT\Capstone Project\watchours\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:417:11)
at View.render (H:\COURSERA\FULL STACK WEB DEVELOPMENT COURSE\CAPSTONE PROJECT\Capstone Project\watchours\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:126:8)
at tryRender (H:\COURSERA\FULL STACK WEB DEVELOPMENT COURSE\CAPSTONE PROJECT\Capstone Project\watchours\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:639:10)
at EventEmitter.render (H:\COURSERA\FULL STACK WEB DEVELOPMENT COURSE\CAPSTONE PROJECT\Capstone Project\watchours\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:591:3)
at ServerResponse.render (H:\COURSERA\FULL STACK WEB DEVELOPMENT COURSE\CAPSTONE PROJECT\Capstone Project\watchours\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:960:7)
at H:\COURSERA\FULL STACK WEB DEVELOPMENT COURSE\CAPSTONE PROJECT\Capstone Project\watchours\app.js:91:7
at Layer.handle_error (H:\COURSERA\FULL STACK WEB DEVELOPMENT COURSE\CAPSTONE PROJECT\Capstone Project\watchours\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
at trim_prefix (H:\COURSERA\FULL STACK WEB DEVELOPMENT COURSE\CAPSTONE PROJECT\Capstone Project\watchours\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:310:13)
at H:\COURSERA\FULL STACK WEB DEVELOPMENT COURSE\CAPSTONE PROJECT\Capstone Project\watchours\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (H:\COURSERA\FULL STACK WEB DEVELOPMENT COURSE\CAPSTONE PROJECT\Capstone Project\watchours\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
at next (H:\COURSERA\FULL STACK WEB DEVELOPMENT COURSE\CAPSTONE PROJECT\Capstone Project\watchours\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a few bugs/issues:

1. You don't exit the function, when an error raised. Because of that, your code sends response twice: first one with error, second one with the data.
2. You don't use promises. It's not a bug, but now it's 2017 and ES7 is already released, you should avoid using callbacks.

The fixed, improved code could looks so:

```
.put(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, (req, res, next) => {
    Episode
      .findById(req.params.episodeId, (err, episode) => {
        req.body.postedBy = req.decoded._id;

        episode.comments.id(req.params.commentId).remove();
        episode.comments.push(req.body);
        return episode.save();
    })
    .then(episode => res.send(episode))
    .catch(next);
})
```

Comment: @alexmac It may be 2017, but you shouldn't assume that OP is using the latest version of javascript. It does take effort to make the switch.

Comment: @DavidKnipe Hmm, who are talking about the latest version? node.js supports promises natively since v4.0.0 (was released two years ago), and with `bluebird` or `Q` since v0.10 or early. So my answer not about new features, it's about using the best approaches and avoiding mistakes when writing new code.

Comment: @alexmac That's true, but there must still be people who are still on earlier versions. I was working on a project on node 0 until about a year ago (async, not promises). And I don't see why promises are necessarily better than callbacks, they're just a different style. Also, if you provide an answer which fixes the bug while at the same time restructuring the whole script, you're in danger of confusing people who read it unnecessarily.

Comment: @DavidKnipe Have you heard about callbacks hell? If you don't see the advantages of using promises, you don't know what are promises and how to use them. I recommend you investigate this thing, when you'll understand them, the new world will open for you, I promise:). What about my answer, I changed the original code, because it contained several anti patterns, and just fixing the bug in the this code, wouldn't be a complete answer.

Comment: @alexmac A new world will open? What can you do with promises that I can't do with `require('async')`? I can do tasks in parallel, in series with dependencies, or anything in between. There's a function to create a task queue to which tasks can be added dynamically. You think I'm just unfamiliar with promises, and there's some truth in that, but maybe it's you who is unfamiliar with `async`. Or maybe you didn't realise I meant the `async` npm module. And I still say that fixing the bug the question was about answers the question, and anything else (especially major restructuring) can confuse.